# Winter Bash 2015 is upon us! Are we in?

Tags: discussion

I've got an email from someone on the Stack Exchange team. It tells me that Winter Bash 2015 is ready, and **will start on 14 December**.

Since there has been such a positive response in previous years of the Bash, **the default this year is we're in**.

So - my question to everyone is do we *want* to be in? Hats are fun, and there will of course be an "I hate hats" option - but it is ultimately a community decision.

Upvote the answer you agree with. If we're out, I need to let the Community Team know by **10 December** - so **on the 9th**, I'll take the highest-voted answer here as consensus, and use that as a response. If there's no highest-voted, I'll just make an executive decision.

Do we want hats?

Comment: Can we get some more context? Winter bash? Hats? What?

Comment: @Martijn were you not around for WB 2014? Essentially, you earn hats (like badges, but... hats) for doing things on the site, which you can put on your avatar in festive spirit. There's a leaderboard per-site and network-wide.

Comment: I still do like these things as much as anyone, but I wish at least equal effort were put into trying things to [improve baseline new user experience](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265671/).  And how about having [open source ads back?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308598).  If we can have them all that's ideal, if not I could live without a hat.  Broken...record...skips...again...

Comment: @HostileFork Open Source ads aren't on **this** site. They are on Stack Overflow, and ads are still hosted (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281524/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2015). Regardless, this site is in beta, and no community ads are available anyway :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, we want hats!

Hats are fun, therefore we're in.

Answer (score -4):

## No, we hate hats!

Hats should never be seen adorning our heads!